# Amazon Alexa Error "The response is invalid"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Facing problem with aws lambda and alexa, I have aws lambda function:

```
               function firebaseData(callback)
                {
                    if(firebase.apps.length == 0) {
                        firebase.initializeApp({
                       serviceAccount: "******",
                       databaseURL:"********"
                        });
                        }
                        var ref = firebase.database().ref();
                        var usersRef = ref.child('users');


                        usersRef.once('value').then(function (snap) {

                       snap.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

                       var childKey = childSnapshot.val();
                       var contact = childKey.Contact;
                      firebase.database().goOffline();
                        callback(contact); 

                       });

                        });
                }

      **************************************************

         function getContactFromSession(intent, session, callback) {
                  const repromptText = null;
                  const sessionAttributes = {};
                  let shouldEndSession = false;

                  firebaseData(function (contact) {
                    let speechOutput = "amy's contact is " + contact;
                    callback(
                      sessionAttributes,
                      buildSpeechletResponse(intent.name, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession)
                     );
                  })    
                }
```

When using contact value by calling `firebaseData(function(contact){})` in

```
getContactFromSession(intent, session, callback) using callback(
                      sessionAttributes,
                      buildSpeechletResponse(intent.name, speechOutput, repromptText, shouldEndSession)
                     );
```

Giving error in Alexa skill output as:

```
Unable to call remote endpoint or the response is invalid
```

What might be wrong with the callback? Can't figure it out.